# Portrait-only presentingViewController's auto layout constraints are unsatisfied while presentedViewController rotates

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, autolayout

In my project, all the view controllers are set to portrait-only except one which is allowed to auto rotate. For those portrait-only view controllers, I only set "Base Value" auto layout constraints. However, when I rotate the portrait-only view controller (still in portrait after rotate) and present the view controller which support auto rotate, the presented view controller rotates to landscape with "**Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints**" warnings.

The "**Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints**" warnings are from the presentedViewController which only support portrait. My question is why this happens? Dose the presentingViewController also rotate with the presentedViewController although it is covered by presentedViewController?

Comment: We need to see your constraint code.

Comment: I set the constraints in storyboard. There is no warning in portrait mode except when I rotate the presentedViewController.